# Given $\sin(A)=x$ and $\cos(B)=y$, find $\tan(2A)$ in terms of $x$ and/or $y$.

Tags: trigonometry

> Given $\sin(A)=x$, and that $90^\circ<A<180^\circ$, find the value of $\tan(2A)$ in terms of $x$ and/or $y$.

From the question I understand that A is in the 2nd quadrant (since sin positive) and B is in the 4th quadrant (since cos positive). However from there I'm stuck. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: What does B have to do with anything?

Comment: I would not say $A$ is in the second quadrant since its sine is positive. I would say $A$ is in the second quadrant since $90^\circ<A<180^\circ$, and its sine is positive since it is in the second quadrant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your conditions $$\tan{A}=\frac{\sin{A}}{\cos{A}},$$ $$\cos{A}=-\sqrt{1-x^2}$$ and

$$\tan2A=\frac{2\tan{A}}{1-\tan^2A}$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: Can down-voter explain us, why did you do it?

Answer (score 0):

$\tan2A = \frac{2\tan A}{1-\tan^{2} A}$. Substituting $\tan A = \frac{\sin A}{\cos A}$ into the expression, we get:
$$ \tan 2A = \frac{2 \frac{\sin A}{\cos A}}{1-\frac{\sin^2 A}{\cos^2 A}}$$

Simplify the expression, you get your answer.